# AES_Encryption problem --> MixColumns fault

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I have a problem with a code I'm trying to produce to represent a round of AES encryption.
My functions: "AddRoundKey", "SubBytes Transformations" & "ShiftRows Transformations" work correctly. (I know because in paper format I have the matrix answers to make sure the code works).

However, I have a weird fault for the Mix_columns function...
To be clear, the function works when I use it with hexadecimal values, but not with decimal values...

To find out, I've written a raw matrix with these hexadecimal values, and another with these decimal values.
And the result is not the same...

Here's the function with some comments to help you understand it better:

```
def aes_mix_columns(byte_matrix):

    fixed_aes_mix_columns = [
        [2, 3, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 1],
        [1, 1, 2, 3],
        [3, 1, 1, 2]
    ]

    after_shift_rows = [
        [0xab, 0x8b, 0x89, 0x35],
        [0x40, 0x7f, 0xf1, 0x05],
        [0xf0, 0xfc, 0x18, 0x3f],
        [0xc4, 0xe4, 0x4e, 0x2f]
    ]

    #Result of : print(byte_matrix) : (you can check each box if you like, but I've already done so, and it's the equivalent of the "after_shift_rows" matrix, but in decimal values.)
    #[
    #    [171, 139, 137, 53],
    #    [64, 127, 241, 5],
    #    [240, 252, 24, 63],
    #    [196, 228, 78, 47]
    #]

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            byte_matrix[i][j] = gf256_mul(fixed_aes_mix_columns[i][0], byte_matrix[0][j]) ^ \
                                gf256_mul(fixed_aes_mix_columns[i][1], byte_matrix[1][j]) ^ \
                                gf256_mul(fixed_aes_mix_columns[i][2], byte_matrix[2][j]) ^ \
                                gf256_mul(fixed_aes_mix_columns[i][3], byte_matrix[3][j])


#Result when I use after_shift_rows[][] :
    # b9 94 57 75
    # e4 8e 16 51
    # 47 20 9a 3f
    # c5 d6 f5 3b
    #
    # --> GOOD ANSWER

    #-------------------------------------

    # Result when I use byte_matrix[][] :
    # b9 94 57 75
    # f6 91 c8 11
    # e3 d1 7d 6b
    # 56 34 d0 bb
    #
    # --> Only the first line is right, the rest is wrong... Why is this?


    return byte_matrix
```

I've written down the output when I use the 2 matrices, and as you can see, the results are not the same.
But I don't understand why, isn't the computer supposed to interpret the decimal value and the hexadecimal value in the same way?

My function seems to work with hexadecimal values, but not with these decimal equivalents.